# How to make normalized frequency distribution plot for 2D matrices?

Tags: matlab

I have two 80*80 matrices. I would like to plot normalized frequency plot. I tried to normalize the 80* 80 grid with the following code:

```
A = per_monsoon_postmon; % (A is my 80*80 matrix)
A = rand (80,80);
minA = repmat(min(A), [size(A, 1), 1]);
normA = max(A) - min(A);
normA = repmat(normA, [length(normA) 1]);

normalizedA = (A - minA)./normA;
```

But this code didn't give me the desired result, as grids with `nan` values also has a number in it. For eg. earlier grid 1*1 is `nan` now it has a value of 0.8340. Could you please help me how to normalize the 2D matrix and then plot frequency distribution plot in MATLAB? Is there a way to directly plot normalized frequency distribution plot?

Comment: What kind of norm do you want? There is a nice matlab answers response maybe this helps you: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/60331-matrix-normalization-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

If you have nan values in your verctor you might have problems. I would first replace the nans (for example with zeros).

Normalisation between 0 and one works like this:

```
 a=rand(80,80); %generates random 80x80 array
a=a-min(min(a)); %shifts the values from 0 to n, min(min() ) because it is 2x2
a=a./max(max(a));% shifts to 0 to 1
```

If you want tot plot these values in 3d I would use a surf plot therefore you first generate the sample values and then feed them the z values

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:80);
surf(x,y,z)
```